# Adding dataframe columns onto another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two dataframes:

df1:

```
Symbol, Open, High, Low, Close
abc,    123,  676,  100, 343
```

df2:

```
Symbol, Target1, Target2
abc,    654,     565
```

I am trying to combine these two dataframes based on symbol, ie: Target1/Target2 must be added as new columns:

```
Symbol, Open, High, Low, Close, Target1, Target2
abc,    123,  676,  100, 343,   654,     565
```

I have tried a some join/merge ideas but can't seem to get it to work.

Please can someone advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `concat` them and pass param `axis=1`:

```
In [7]:

pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1)
Out[7]:
  Symbol  Open  High  Low  Close Symbol  Target1  Target2
0    abc   123   676  100    343    abc      654      565
```

Or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) on 'Symbol' column:

```
In [8]:

df.merge(df1, on='Symbol')
Out[8]:
  Symbol  Open  High  Low  Close  Target1  Target2
0    abc   123   676  100    343      654      565
```